# JPEG library in Qt

Tags: qt

I am trying to run a Qt program on a distant device. My promoter made some changes with opencv version due to previous errors and now I have the following error which I had not before:

> (HelloWord:28603): GdkPixbuf-WARNING **: Bug! loader 'png' didn't set an error on failure
>   (HelloWord:28603): Gtk-WARNING **: Error loading theme icon 'edit-find' for stock: Erreur interne : le module de chargement d'images « png » n'est pas parvenu à terminer une opération, mais il n'a pas donné la raison de son échec
>   (HelloWord:28603): GdkPixbuf-WARNING **: Bug! loader 'png' didn't set an error on failure
>   (HelloWord:28603): Gtk-WARNING **: Error loading theme icon 'edit-find' for stock: Erreur interne : le module de chargement d'images « png » n'est pas parvenu à terminer une opération, mais il n'a pas donné la raison de son échec
>   Wrong JPEG library version: library is 62, caller expects 80
>   The program has unexpectedly finished.

However, when I try to uninstall libjpeg62, it says it's not installed... I am a bit confused and would appreciate any help

Here is what my terminal does:

> dev@fermi01:~$ sudo apt-get remove libjpeg62
>   [sudo] password for dev:
>   Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
>   Construction de l'arbre des dépendances
>   Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
>   Package 'libjpeg62' is not installed, so not removed. Did you mean 'libjpeg62:i386'?
>   0 mis à jour, 0 nouvellement installés, 0 à enlever et 320 non mis à jour.

and it seems that libjpeg8 is installed, however...

Comment: Post the stack trace. We want to see why Qt or maybe it is OpenCV to blame. The piece of code won't hurt too.

Comment: Are you sure you're loading a JPEG image ?
Because looking at the errors, the Gtk warnings mention it couldn't load a "PNG". Regarding the jpeg library, it looks like you have installed the i386 library on a x86_64 system? If you want to remove it you sould call `$ sudo apt-get remove libjpeg62:i386`

Answer (score 0):

A kind or rough guess.

libjpeg is basically from **Independent JPEG Group**.

libjpeg 6 series is a way old library.

Download 8 series source code from **below link** and build new libjpeg library and then replace your old ones (I suggest you to download **jpegsr8.zip**)   .

http://www.ijg.org/files/

Actually the current stable version is 9 series. The latest source code is available in below link. But I doubt your application can take this.... so try with 8 series first.

http://www.infai.org/jpeg/

Comment: It seems that libjpeg8 is installed and libjpeg62 uninstalled but Qt error says the contrary...

Comment: How do you know that libjpeg8 is available....? Could you please search for it in your system.